# matrix calculator bug - not working properly

Tags: c, pointers, debugging, matrix

My code is building a matrix calculator. I have an array of matrices, a function to build the matrix, that gets a pointer to the wanted matrix (one of 6) and a pointer to an array of parameters to enter the matrix. another function is print_mat to print the matrix.

The problem is: I have these matrices: MAT_A, MAT_B......MAT_F.
when I enter parameters to MAT_X, it also showed om MAT_X-1. for instance - if I put parameters to MAT_B, somehow MAT_A gets updated too.

---

```
MAT type definition: typedef double MAT[N][N];

MAT array:     MAT matrices[6];

printing matrix function: 

void print_mat(MAT * mat1){
int i=0,j=0;
printf("the matrix is:\n\n");
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < N ; ++j){
        printf("%.2f    ",*mat1[i][j]);
        if (j==N-1) /* end of line, last parameter on this line so move to the next one */
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

}

put parameters in matrix function:

```
void read_mat (MAT  *mat1 , double * parameters){
int i=0,j=0,index=0;
for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < N ; ++j){
        *(mat1)[i][j]=parameters[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

}

How I call the functions to use: (relevant cases are case 0 and 1)

```
void execute(MAT *matrices,int *parameters, double *scalars, int command_index){
switch (command_index){
    case 0:
        read_mat(&matrices[parameters[0]],scalars);
        break;
    case 1:
        print_mat(&matrices[parameters[0]]);
        break;
    case 2:
        add_mat(&matrices[parameters[0]],&matrices[parameters[1]],&matrices[parameters[2]]);
        break;
    case 3:
        sub_mat(&matrices[parameters[0]],&matrices[parameters[1]],&matrices[parameters[2]]);
        break;
    case 4:
        mul_mat(&matrices[parameters[0]],&matrices[parameters[1]],&matrices[parameters[2]]);
        break;
    case 5:
        mul_scalar(&matrices[parameters[0]],scalars,&matrices[parameters[1]]);
        break;
    case 6:
        trans_mat(&matrices[parameters[0]],&matrices[parameters[1]]);
        break;
    default: /* stop command */
        stop();
        break;
}
```

}

---

command: read_mat MAT_B,1,2.3456,-7.89
command: print_mat MAT_B
result: 
the matrix is: //(MAT_B)

1.00    2.35    -7.89    0.00

0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

but at the same time MAT_A:
command: print_mat MAT_A

0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

1.00    2.35    -7.89    0.00

0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00

(while it should be all zeros)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to receive a `MAT`, you need

```
void print_mat(MAT mat1){ // same as void print_mat(double mat1[N][N]){
```

instead of

```
void print_mat(MAT * mat1){ // You don't want a pointer to a 2D array
```

and here

```
printf("%.2f    ",*mat1[i][j]);
```

you don't want to dereference, instead

```
printf("%.2f    ", mat1[i][j]);
```

Same for `read_mat()`

Comment: it works!! thank you so so much!!!!!
a question, why didnt it work...? I wanted to send a pointer to the function and not the whole matrix... why wasn't that good?

Comment: An array is already (decays into) a pointer when passed to a function, in other words, if you want to set the values of an array is enough to pass the array, not his address, you pass the address when you want to change the value of the pointer itself (the address of the array or where it points to).

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler complain here somewhere about incompatible types? Wouldn't it then be a matter of "turn warnings of your compiler on!"?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, yes, it should emit a warning in this case